# Dynamic multidemension Array with Date keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

how do I loop the newly created dynamic array by key and sub array.

```
var days = new Array();
$.each(json_object, function(r, row) {

    var online_date = new Date(row.date_field * 1000);
    var day_key = '' + online_date.getFullYear() + '' + (online_date.getMonth()+1) + '' + online_date.getDate() + '';

    if(!days[day_key]) {
        days[day_key] = [];
    }

    days[day_key][r] = row;

});

console.log('days.length');
console.log(Object.keys(days).length);
// 3 days woth of data.. 
// 20, 30 records each day... 

for(var d = 0; d < Object.keys(days).length; d++) {
    var day = days[d];

    // day is undefined
    console.log(day);

    // I want KEY for 'day_key' and the data rows...

}
```

I'm using jQuery or basic JS. 
If I filter or sort the array I loose my Keys, which I need as I want to graph out per day.

Thanks.

Comment: You are declaring `days` as an array, but if you are doing `Object,keys(days)`, then days should be an object, like `var days = {}`

Comment: Then how do I reference it? If I don't use the object.keys() then the length is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `days` as an object, not an array:

```
var days = {};
$.each(json_object, function(r, row) {

    var online_date = new Date(row.date_field * 1000);
    var day_key = '' + online_date.getFullYear() + '' + (online_date.getMonth()+1) + '' + online_date.getDate() + '';

    if(!days[day_key]) {
        days[day_key] = []; // Define an array for the rows to go into
    }

    days[day_key].push(row); // Add the row to the array

});

console.log('days.length');
console.log(Object.keys(days).length);
// 3 days worth of data.. 
// 20, 30 records each day... 

Object.keys(days).forEach(day => {
    console.log(day);

    // I want KEY for 'day_key' and the data rows...
    // The array of rows for the day are available
    console.log(`Rows for ${day}: `,days[day])

})
```

I think this will do what you want